# How to fix pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch very strange?

Tags: gazebo, kinect, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 11.04 with ROS electric.

I try to run:

```
  roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch
```

It shows:

[image: image description]

How to fix it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28387/how-to-fix-pr2_kinect_empty_world.launch-very-strange?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this issue was addressed in [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/ticket/5185).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-02-24**:
This ticket says that 'fixed in r54208. running prerelease tests. '. Does it means that I can dist-upgrade ROS electric and fix that problem now or waiting for several days? Or how can I update it? Thank you~

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-24**:
check http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html and look for p2_common 1.6.2.  I am not sure exactly how long it takes between ros-shadow-fixed and the ros repo.